# Microsoft JScript toUpperCase returns type unknown

Tags: javascript, jscript

I have this JScript file doing a natural-compare sorting and somehow this problem keeps occurring:

The array is created through getting all files in a folder, then I want to sort it. For some (random?) files, the first time comparing works, the second the variable's type becomes `unknown` after the `.toUpperCase()`.

My Code:

```
function naturalCompare(a, b) {
    var ax = [], bx = [];

    a.toString();
    b.toString();

    a = a + "";
    b = b + "";

    a = a.toUpperCase();
    b = b.toUpperCase();


    a.replace(/(\d+)|(\D+)/g, function(_, $1, $2) { ax.push([$1 || Infinity, $2 || ""]) });
    b.replace(/(\d+)|(\D+)/g, function(_, $1, $2) { bx.push([$1 || Infinity, $2 || ""]) });

    while(ax.length && bx.length) {
        var an = ax.shift();
        var bn = bx.shift();
        var nn = (an[0] - bn[0]) || an[1].localeCompare(bn[1]);
        if(nn) return nn;
    }
    return ax.length - bx.length;
}
```

I copied this (dunno where anymore). Normally it works, this happened only just now.

And yes, `unknown`, not `undefined`.

Comment: "unknown"? Or `undefined`? And show a [MCVE]. There's probably more going on.

Comment: please include your code

Comment: Have you tried type(variable) what it is returning or force a cast

Comment: I got the type with typeof(a), that's the one where the error occurred. type(a) tells me it wants an object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, seems to be something with a few filenames, it only happens with this particular folder, which contains files with names from html which could potentially be the problem.

Anyways, thanks for all the help, I'll just let those few files be.